# Should we initialize our Fully Connected Model with custom filter weights at the beginning of each epoch?

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, initializer

I am employing a Fully Convolutional Neural Network (FCN) for the image segmentation purpose within the Keras library. I have about 35 epochs in my network (from experience).

Due to some physical consequences, I prefer to apply a unique custom initializer (3*3) with zero corner cells (weights). My question is that:
Should I apply the custom initializer (3*3) at the beginning of each epoch or just before the first epoch?
My understanding is that if I apply the custom initializer at the beginning of each epoch, this makes every epoch literally equal to each other. Am I correct?

Since after the first epoch, the point is finding the optimized filter. If the starting point of all epochs be similar, the concluding point will be the same (since, each epoch withstands the exact same blocks of layers with exact same initializer).

All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with your understanding that with custom/random initialization of kernel weights at the beginning of every epoch, we're essentially throwing away the weights learnt by the model at the end of every epoch and starting from scratch in the next epoch. Hence, custom/random initialization of weights/biases are usually performed only at the beginning of training the model.

But, in the case where custom initialization of kernel values needs to be performed while training the model (in your case, assigning corner weight values of the filter to 0 at the beginning of every epoch), you could *multiply* the learned filter weights with a **mask** the same dimension as that of the filter and which contains 0 at the corners and 1 at remaining indices.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample coding in Keras on how to apply this mask at the beginning of each epoch?

Comment: This involves getting the kernel weights by using `get_weights()` function in keras and then multiplying this obtained filter values with a mask that ignores the corner elements. An example of a mask `M` for a `(3,3,1)` filter would be `M = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]`. To provide more details, I might need to refer your code.